# Unable to Enforce List Relationships

Tags: 2013, lookup-column

I'm trying to set isRelationShip to **true** in some lookupfields in my project.

I don't know why I'm not be able to perform this:
[image]

Always, after doing fieledLookup.Update(), **IsRelationship** is set to false with no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my method to:

```
public static void RestrictDeleteOnLookupField(SPWeb web, SPList list, Guid fieldGuid)
{
    SPField field = list.Fields[fieldGuid];
    SPFieldLookup fieldLookup = field as SPFieldLookup;
    fieldLookup.Indexed = true;
    // check relationship whether is unable, it has to enable before set delete-behaviour
    if (!fieldLookup.IsRelationship)
    {
        if(fieldLookup.RelationshipDeleteBehavior == SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        {
            fieldLookup.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior.None;
        }
        fieldLookup.IsRelationship = true;
        fieldLookup.Update();
        list.Update();
    }

    // set restrict behaviour
    fieldLookup.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior.Restrict;
    fieldLookup.Update();
}
```

Changing the *RelationshipDeleteBehavior* attribute causes that *Update* takes into account the value of *IsRelationship*.